# Exercise: An homeomorphism between a complex torus and $S^1\times S^1$

Tags: general-topology

Given a lattice $\left <w_1,w_2\right> =\Lambda \subset \mathbb C$, I have to find an explicit homeomorphism between $\mathbb C/\Lambda$ and $S^1\times S^1$. Here there is my solution:

For every $z=aw_1+bw_2$ (with $a,b\in\mathbb R$)  define $f:\mathbb C\longrightarrow S^1\times S^1$ with $f(z)=(e^{2\pi i(a-\lfloor a\rfloor)}, e^{2\pi i(b-\lfloor b\rfloor)})$. Then we can consider the equivalence relation on $\mathbb C$ given by $z_1\sim z_2$ when $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$. Passing to the quotient we should have the required homeomorphism.

Is it right? Is there a more straightforward function?

Comment: This is straightforward enough

Comment: But I notice right now that the floor function $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is not continuous!

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't make $e^{2\pi i (a - \lfloor a \rfloor)}$ discontinuous. $\lfloor a \rfloor$ isn't continuous, $a - \lfloor a \rfloor$ isn't too. But for last function the jump at each integer point is an integer number ($1$, of course). And that fits well with $e^{2\pi i z}$

Comment: It's easier to just define $f (z) = (\exp 2 \pi a i, \exp 2 \pi b i)$.

Comment: ... which is exactly equivalent to original formula, but looks easier, agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems right. Note, though, that you should not "consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ given by $z_1 \sim z_2$ when $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$", but you should prove that that is the equivalence relation induced by $\Lambda$.

To then prove that the induced map is a homeomorphism: use $f(z) = (\exp(2\pi a i), \exp(2\pi b i))$, as indicated by Zhen Lin in the comments, to see that $f$ is continuous; then argue that it is a bijection; and finally prove that it's closed by using the fact that a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed. For the last point, you'll need to show that ${\mathbb C}/\Lambda$ is compact, which needs the (unstated) assumption that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are not colinear.